# Flutter TypeAheadFormField suggestion list is not positioning after the validation in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-typeahead

Am using flutter_typeahead package. So now am facing an issue after the validation error UI is not perfect. The problem is if I clear the TypeAheadFormField it will show an error message with that suggestion list like no items found, so I will click on system back or keyboard done it will dismiss that suggestion list. Then if I type something in that textfield the suggestion list is not positioning in a correct place. it should be down to that TypeAheadFormField. Only In this scenario it is happening. Kindly find the attached screenshot for the reference.
Actually it is taking error message height I think so.

[image]